# es6 import - fancybox is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fancybox

Im trying to use fancybox in a project, however when importing it, I still get an error (fancybox is not a function) - This is what im doing:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery'; 
import 'fancybox';
```

And later on, im trying to do:

```
// export jQuery for others scripts to use /inline scripts in some controls
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;

$(".list__item--img").fancybox({
'titlePosition': 'inside',
'transitionIn': 'none',
'transitionOut': 'none',
"padding": 0,
"overlayOpacity": 0.8,
"overlayColor": "#000",
"autoDimensions": false,
"width": 355,
"height": 190,
"showCloseButton": false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [fancybox npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancybox) it looks like you need to pass your jquery object to it.

```
fancybox($) // or fancybox(jQuery)
```

> This is where fancybox attaches itself to the jquery object.

Otherwise there is always the old fashion of way of including the second script tag on the page.